# как работает NSTimer xCode7.2 Swift 2.0 =?

Tags: ios, swift

NSTimer с режимом repeat при повторах создает каждый раз новый объект в памяти или нет = ? т е это один и тот же таймер работает и ничего лишнего в оперативке не остается = ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSTimer с режимом repeat при повторах НЕ создает каждый раз новый объект в памяти